# NullPointerException thrown when I try to write an Object via ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am sending an Object to a server which is a wrapper class for the data that I am sending. I debugged it and it connects fine but when it reaches the part where my client is writing the object to the output stream, it throws a nullpointerexception.

Main.java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client client = new Client("Client", "localhost");
    Server server = new Server("Room", "Server");

    Thread tclient = new Thread(client);
    Thread tserver = new Thread(server);

    tserver.start();
    tclient.start();

    Message m = new Message();
    m.addValue("Message", "Dummy Text");
    client.transmit(m);


}
```

Client.java

```
private String username, ip;
private ObjectOutputStream writer;

public Socket socket;

public Client(String username, String ip) {

    this.username = username;
    this.ip = ip;

}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        socket = new Socket(ip, 22600);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.addValue("Username", username);
        writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        writer.writeObject(msg);
        writer.flush();
        Listener listener = new Listener(socket, Client.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

public void transmit(Message msg) {

    try {

        System.out.println(1);
        writer.writeObject(msg); // NullPointerException here
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println(2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.Client.transmit(Client.java:45)
at com.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: **Obviously** you got an exception and suppressed it in your empty catch block, so `writer` was null when you called it from `transmit()`. Don't write code like this. You should probably create the `Socket` and the output stream in the constructor for `Client`, and let the `IOException` be thrown so you don't proceed past the exception as though it hadn't happened. But you're really expected to be able to deal with NPEs by yourself. You're also never closing the socket.

Comment: This is why you do not use empty catch blocks.

Comment: Sorry, this was a test application. I was going to be implementing this with a GUI so I did not place the printStackTrace method in the catch blocks. I will be more meticulous next time about remembering to print the stack trace before I finish my final application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the problem related to `Thread` execution,seems your `transmit` method is executed before the `run` method finish it's execution.

Use proper `wait/notify` mechanism to ensure the desired result.

Comment: I don't think much of this solution. Creating everything in the constructor woudl be a lot simpler.